# Storing and querying for announcements between two datetimes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

## Background

I have to design a table to store announcements in DynamoDB. Each announcement has the following structure:

```
{
    "announcementId": "(For the frontend to identify an announcement to the backend)",
    "author": "(id of author)",
    "displayStartDatetime": "",
    "displayEndDatetime": "",
    "title": "",
    "description": "",
    "image": "(A url to an image)",
    "link": "(A single url to another page)"
}
```

As we are still designing the table, alterations to the structure are permitted. In particular, `announcementId`, `displayStartDatetime` and `displayEndDatetime` can be changed.

The main access pattern is to find the current announcements. Users have a webpage which they can see all current announcements and their details.

Every announcement has a date for when to start showing it (`displayStartDatetime`) and when to stop showing it (`displayEndDatetime`). The announcement is should still be kept in the table after the current datetime is past `displayEndDatetime` for reference for admins.

The start and end datetime are precise to the minute.

## Problem

Ideally, I would like a way to query the table for all the current announcements in one query.

However, I have come to the conclusion that it is impossible to fuse two datetimes in one sort key because it is impossible to order two pieces of data of equal importance (e.g. storing the timestamps as a string will mean one will be more important/greater than the other).

Hence, as a compromise, I would like to sort the table values by `displayEndDatetime` so that I can filter out past announcements. This is because, as time goes on, there will be more past announcements than future announcements, so it will be more beneficial to optimise that.

## Compromised Solution

Currently, my (not very good) solutions are:

1. Use one "hot" partition key and use the `displayEndDatetime` as the sort key.

This allows me to filter out past announcements, but it also means that all the data is in a single partition. I could run a scheduled job every now and then to move the past announcements to a different spaced out partitions.

2. `Scan` through the table

I believe `Scan` will look at every item in the table before it performs any filtering.  This solution doesn't seem as good as 1. but it would be the simplest to implement and it would allow me to keep `announcementId` as the partition key.

3. `Scan` a GSI of the table

Since `Scan` will look through every item, it may be more efficient to create a GSI (`announcementId (PK), displayEndDatetime (SK)`) and scan through that to retrieve all the `announcementId`s which have not passed. After that, another request could be made to get all the announcements.

## Question

What is the most optimised solution for storing all announcements and then finding current announcements when using DynamoDB?

Although I have listed a few possible solutions for sorting the `displayEndDatetime`, the main point is still finding announcements between the start and end datetime.

## Edit

Here are the answers to @tugberk's questions on the background:

- What is the rate of writes you anticipate receiving (i.e. peak writes per second you need to handle)?

I am uncertain of how the admins will use this system, announcements can be very regular (about 3/day) or very infrequent (about 3/month).

- How much new data do you anticipate storing daily, and how do you think this will grow?

As mentioned above, this could be about 3 announcements a day or 3 a month. This is likely to remain the same for as long as I should be concerned about.

- What is the rate of reads (e.g. peak reads per second)?

I would expect the peak reads per second to be around 500-1000 reads/s. This number is expected to grow as there are more users.

- How many announcements a user can see at a time (i.e. what's avg/max number of announcements will be visible at any point in time)? Practically thinking, this shouldn't be more than a few (e.g. 10-20 at most).

I would expect the maxmimum number of viewable announcements to be up to 30-40. This is because there could be multiple long-running announcements along with short-term announcements. On average, I would expect about 5-10 announcements.

- What is the data inconsistency gap you are happy to have here (i.e. do you need seconds level precision, or would you be happy to have ~1min delay on displaying and hiding announcements)?

I think the speed which the announcement starts showing is important, especially if the admins decide that this is a good platform for urgent announcements (likely urgent to the minute). However, when it stops showing is less important, but to avoid confusing the users the announcement should stop display at most 4 hours after it is past its display end datetime.

Comment: I can guess it but it would be good to know what's your exact question here is :)

Comment: @tugberk you're right, I have edited the question to state the question more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of questions are always hard to answer here as there is so many assumptions on the answer as it's really hard to have all the facts. But I will try to give you so ideas, which may help you think about your data storage choice as well as giving you further options.

### I know what I am doing, and really need to use DynamoDB

> Edited this answer based on the OP's answers to my original questions.

As you really need to us DynamoDB for this for internal reasons, I think it's more suitable to store the data in two DynamoDB tables for both serving reads and writes as nearly all access patterns I can think of will hit multiple partitions if you have one table. You can get away with a GSI, but it's not too straight forward how to do it, and I am not sure whether there is any advantage to doing it that way.

The core thing you need to optimize for is the reads as you mentioned it can go up to 2K/rps which is big enough to make this the part where you optimize your architecture against. Based on your assumptions of having 3 announcements a day, it's nothing to worry about as far as the writes are concerned.

General idea is this:

- I would consider using one DynamoDB table to handle writes where you can configure `author` identifier as the partition key, and `announcement` identifier as the sort key (and make your primary key as the combination of both). This will allow you to query all the announcements for a given author easily.
- I would also have a second DynamoDB table to handle reads, where you will only store active announcements which your application can query and retrieve all of it with a `Scan` query (i.e. `O(N)`), which is not a concern as you mentioned there will only be `30-40` active announcments at any point in time. Let's imagine this to be even 500, you are still OK with this structure. In terms of partition and sort key, I would just have an `active` boolean field as the partition key, which you will always have it as `true`, you can have the announcement id as the sort key, and make the combination of both as the primary key. If you care about the sort of these announcements, you can adjust the sort key accordingly but make sure it's unique (i.e. consider concatenating the announcement identifier, e.g. `{displayBeginDatetime-in-yyyyMMddHHmmss-format}-{announcementId}`. With this way you will guarantee that you will only hit one partition. However, you can actually simplify this and have the announcement identifier as the partition key and primary key as I am nearly sure that DynamoDB will store all your data in one partition as it's going to be so small. Better to confirm this though as I am not 100% sure. The point here is that you are much better of ensuring hitting one partition with this query.

Here is how this may work, where there are some edge cases I am overlooking:

- record the write inside the first DynamoDB for an announcement. When an announcement is written, configure `displayEndDatetime` as the [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) of that row, with the assumption that you don't need this record in this table when an announcement expires.
- have a job running for `N` minute (one or more, depending on the data inconsistency gap you can handle), which will `Scan` the entire DynamoDB table across partitions (do it in a paginated way), and makes decisions on which announcements are currently visible. Then, write your data into the second DynamoDB table, which will handle the reads, in the structure we have established above so that your consumer can read from this w/o worrying about any filtering as the data is already filtered (e.g. all the announcements here are visible ones). Note that `Scan` is fine here as you are running this once every `N` minutes, with the assumption that you are ok with at least 1 minute + processing time data inconsistency gap. I would suggest running this every 10 minutes or so, if you don't have strong data consistency requirements.
- On the read storage system, also configure `displayEndDatetime` as the [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.htm) for the row so that it gets automatically deleted.
- [Configure DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) on the first DynamoDB table, which has 24 hours retention and exactly once delivery guarantee, and have a lambda consumer of this stream, which to handle when an item is deleted (will happen when TTL kicks in for a particular row) to keep a record of this announcements somewhere else, for longer retention reasons, and will need to expose it through different access pattern (e.g. show all the announcements per author so that they can reenable old announcements), as you mentioned in you question. You can [configure a lambda event sourcing with DynamoDb streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html), which will allow you to handle failures with retries, etc. Make sure that your logic in these lambdas are idempotent so that you can retry safely.

> The below is the parts from my original question, which are still relevant to anyone who might be trying to achieve the same. So, I will leave them here but they are less relevant as the OP needs to use DynamoDB.

### Why DynamoDB?

First of all, I would question why you need DynamoDB for this, as it seems like your requirements are more read heavy than it's being write heavy, where I think DynamoDB shines the most due to its partitioned out of the box nature.

Below questions would help you understand whether you really need DynamoDB for this, or can you get away with a more flexible data storage system:

- what is the rate of writes you anticipate receiving (i.e. peak writes per second you need to handle)?
- how much new data do you anticipate storing daily, and how do you think this will grow?
- what is the rate of reads (e.g. peak reads per second)?
- How many announcements a user can see at a time (i.e. what's avg/max number of announcements will be visible at any point in time)? Practically thinking, this shouldn't be more than a few (e.g. 10-20 at most). This will help you understand whether you need will be OK pulling all the visible announcements in one go, or need a pagination system.
- What is the data inconsistency gap you are happy to have here (i.e. do you need seconds level precision, or would you be happy to have ~1min delay on displaying and hiding announcements)?

### Actually, I don't need DynamoDB

Based on my assumptions on your consumption and admin needs for this use case, I believe you don't need DynamoDB for this with the assumption of not having high number of writes for this (which might be wrong), and if these assumptions are correct, the above is a super over engineered solution for you. Let's say it's correct, I think you are better of using PostgreSQL for this, which can give you easy ability to change your access pattern as you see fit with further indexing, and for the current access pattern you have, you can have a range query over the start and end times.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have internal reasons for using DynamoDB–and they aren't about scalability. I don't want to use DynamoDB, but I have to. So, I am looking for ways to at least make the solution work effectively.

Comment: Makes sense. What’s the max number of visible announcements will be at any point in time?

Comment: I have just edited my question to include answers to your questions

Comment: I have edited my answer, giving you an idea on how this can be done by seeing the read side as the most critical optimisation factor since you have 2K/rps on that. 3 writes a day is nothing. So, really, really not worry about that part too much. YMMV with my solution though as there is a few moving parts but as I said, it optimises your architecture towards serving the reads fast. Hope it helps in some way.